# Why do we say on the team and not in the team?

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

What is it about the word "team" that makes it uniquely take the preposition "on" ?

And yet, the word "club" is similar in meaning; and we can be in a club.

Comment: Could you provide an example including a link, please? I'm certain that people also say "*He is the best* **in the team**", not too sure if "*He's the best* **on the team**" is as popular, but it sounds acceptable to my ears.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"on" vs "in" tends to be the result of **metaphor** - how we understand things in terms of other things.  "in" makes sense if you think of a group of people, and the team member is **in** the middle of that group.

However, imagine writing the team names out on paper, compiling the team list.  The player's name would be **on** the page, and if the page defines the team (which it does, in terms of listing who is in the team), then the player is **on** the team.

So, when people say "in the team" they may be thinking of an actual group of people, standing by the pitch, say, and when they say "on the team", they may be thinking of a list of players, and perhaps the process of deciding who is on that list.

As another example, think of someone saying "I play **in** a softball team".  They are thinking of the other players.  But in another situation they might say "I'm **on** the team for the easter tournament", meaning that they have been **selected**, ie added to a list.

Both metaphors are equally valid, and so "on" and "in" are both acceptable.

On reflection, I could have simplified this explanation by saying that "team" has multiple meanings:  one meaning is the actual group of players, and another meaning is the **list** of players.  We use "in" with the group and "on" with the list.